# Special characters in CSV and fgetcsv

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have CSV file with special characters ØÅÆ
When I use fgetcsv, it just ignores the rest of the string. I tried var_dump for the row, but I got it like this: ���

This is the code that I have:

```
if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                var_dump($data); die;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
```

I tried adding this before my code `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');`
but without any luck. Do you have any advice?

Some sample data - first row from CSV:

```
VAR,E,5704617332886,500,11,"TURKISøåæØÅÆ","110"
```

Comment: you can try sending a **header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');** from PHP? Might solve the issue when printing the data.

Comment: I have that already on the file top where am I printing data

Comment: ah... Bummer :) Can you provide some sample data in your question, for testing purposes?

Comment: added some sample data

Comment: well, the header comment I stated, works like a charm to me? Setting the header before of the var_dump (and your code) prints the sample as-is, without ignoring parts of the line?

Comment: Is the CSV nice encode?

Comment: #DavidLevel I think it is properly encoded. 
#UrGuardian4ngel I have a class that I instanciate in a file that have header set already. And inside the class method I do the var_dump

Answer (score 0):

The proper encoding should be ISO-8859-1. That was the problem